# Why I press [enter] in Vim, the backslash always occur?

Tags: vim, enter, backslash

I can't find problems anywhere :)

[image: something like this]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question and is better suited to [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](http://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Additionally, you need to show us / link to your Vim configuration (`.vimrc`)

Comment: Without seeing your config, I'm going to guess that "eol:\" is in your `listchars` setting and you have `list` set.

Comment: Thank you guys, my raspberry pi happens to have something wrong that can't start up, so I reburn the Raspbian. And then configurate vim carefully . Luckily it runs normally.